# TelegramBot -> Callback кнопка крутит индикацию

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, telegrambots

работаю с InlineKeyboardButton
вопросов никаких не возникает, при отладке и по логам все отрабатывает штатно.
но при некоторых сценариях, на кнопках появляется какая то индикация....
индикация чего крутится в углу кнопки?
как это устранить/обработать?
[image: кругля индикация сверху в углу]

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку боту отправляется CallbackQuery. Вам нужно на него ответить: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery

Comment: @kami, вы хотите сказать, что каждый раз как только мой бот получает объект класса CallbackQuery, я должен отвечать объектом класса AnswerCallbackQuery?
Мне нужно менять клавиатуру и я хочу отвечать объектом класса EditMessageText. Как мне быть в этом случае? очень не красиво смотрится эта индикация.
Может быть можно как то по callback_query_id передать инфу через метаданные, о том что колбэк получен и обработан?

Comment: по получению AnswerCallbackQuery Телеграм понимает, что действие пользователя вами принято и обработано. Любое другое действие (редактирование сообщения, например) не является сигналом об обработке коллбака, потому что "после" не значит "вследствие". Ничего не мешает в обработчике отправить И AnswerCallbackQuery И выполнить требуемые мероприятия по редактированию.

Comment: @kami, я понял вашу мысль, спасибо! Однако нигде еще не встречал чтобы в боте каждое нажатие на inline кнопку сопровождалось уведомлением сверху либо во весь экран, я так понимаю его не избежать? или параметр не обязательный?

Comment: В ссылке на метод, которую я приложил в первом комментарии, указаны и обязательность параметров и "что будет если значение параметра..."

Comment: @kami, спасибо, это работает :)